# WD My Cloud EX2 not staying connected

Tags: networking, nas, plex

I have a WD EX2 My Cloud NAS that I bought in 2015. I've never been able to get it to stay mounted on any of my machines. On my Windows 10 Pro system, I can mount it as a network drive just fine but after some amount of time it just disconnects. Reconnecting is as simple as trying to open the drive in explorer, but unless I do that it's dead. I have also mounted this on an iMac, with pretty much the same effect. If I don't use it, it drops the mount and I have to open the drive in finder to re-mount it.

Where this really sucks is this is my plex content nas. So trying to use either my PC or the mac as a plex server fails. I'm constantly trying to start a movie from the pc or mac plex servers on apple tv and stuck staring at a spinning wheel. I have to then go to the server that the apple tv is connected to, open the nas to get it to re-mount and then I can watch a movie.

I did use the plex server on the nas itself, but more and more lately I get the error that the server isn't powerful enough to convert video.

Anyone know the cause of this problem and how to fix it? Really don't want to buy more hardware just because I can't get the wd nas to stay connected.

Comment: Have you checked if you have the latest firmware? Current MyCloud enclosures update automatically, but yours might not.

Comment: There seems to be a thread of possible solutions on the WD forums: https://community.wd.com/t/compilation-of-windows-10-methods-steps-and-solutions/142576 Have you tried any of these?

Comment: @Mokubai great link- let me try some of those solutions and I'll get back to the thread